# Cannot redeclare hash()

Tags: php

```
<?php
function hash($val, $key){
    $chrs = explode($val, "");
    for($c=0; $c<count($chrs); $c++){
          $ascii[$c]=ord($chrs[$c]);
    }
    $digi = explode($key,"");
    for($c=0; $c<count($digi); $c++){
        $nascii[$c]= $ascii[$c]+$digi[$c];
        $fhash[$c] = $nascii[$c];
    }
}
?>
```

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare hash() in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hash.php on line 12

What is wrong with my simple php code?

Answer (score 3):

*[`hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)* is already a PHP inbuilt function. Name your function to something else.